# I am accessing G Suite logs via BigQuery but some log data appears to be missing

Tags: google-bigquery

My organisation set up BigQuery to access G Suite logs following this official guide:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9079365

We are particularly interested in Drive activity and use this table for analysis:
**gsuite-data-logs.[custom name].activity**

However, there are discrepancies that cannot be explained. For example,a folder containing several images was uploaded the same day, the folder shared and BigQuery can only see half of them. Simple SQL searched for the missing file IDs returns zero rows, yet the files are still listed in the folder.

Any thoughts why this might be the case?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

- Mike

Comment: Have you allowed 48 hours so all the logs can be available in BigQuery, [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9079365)? Also, [according](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566?hl=en) to the documentation there are different lag time for each item in your audit log. So maybe your discrepancy it is due to the fact not all your data was uploaded. Did it help you?

Comment: Hi Alexandre,

The logs were made available into Big Query a year ago and the files in question were uploaded 4 years ago, so plenty of time has elapsed.

It does appear that not all data was uploaded, though, but I am trying to discover why.

Comment: I understand. Have you checked if there is any missing data recently?

Comment: The ability to check for more recent missing files is no longer available, unfortunately. We we comparing using a 3rd-party audit tool that was picking these up but not BigQuery for some reason.